# Is there runtime polymorphism in C# combined with generics?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have 2 classes that inherit from the same generic abstract class. Inheriting and implementing the methods with a type works fine, but I can't figure out how to do late binding with an instance of that abstract class.

```
 internal class NormalField : GenericClass<List<List<int>>>
    {
        protected override List<List<int>> doSomethingWithTheField(List<List<int>> field)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override List<int> getFieldRow(int row)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

internal class ComplexField : GenericClass<List<List<ComplexCell>>>
    {
        protected override List<List<ComplexCell>> doSomethingWithTheField(List<List<ComplexCell>> field)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override List<int> getFieldRow(int row)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

 public class ComplexCell
    {
        int field;
        int? secondField;
    }

public abstract class GenericClass<T>
    {
        public T Field;
        protected abstract T doSomethingWithTheField(T field); //class uses this internally 
        public abstract List<int> getFieldRow(int row); //used by another object
    }
```

Unfortunately I have to declare the type before compiling so I cant dynamically assign another instance of the abstract class to a property.

```
 public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
               // I have to specify the type for the interface here and can't assign a complexfield later
               GenericClass instance = new NormalField(); //not possible
                instance =  new ComplexField();
                instance.getFieldRow(2);
            }
    
        }
```

A possible solution I came up with would be to seperate the getFieldRow() method from the abstract class and create a new interface with only the getFieldRow() method. Since there are no generics involved this would work, but is there also a way to do this with a abstract class with generics?

Comment: You need a (possibly `abstract`) non-generic base class (or `interface`) for the generic type, you use this type to store any instance of `GenericClass`. For example you can have a function on the base class `DoSomethingWithInternalGenericFieldWeDontNeedToKnowAbout()` where the generic class deals with the internal field. The point is that you won't see the generics on the outside and don't need to deal with it, it's all internal to the actual instantiated object

Answer (score 0):

```
GenericClass<List<List<int>>>
```

and

```
GenericClass<List<List<ComplexCell>>>
```

are not the same base class